# How to use \textquote

Tags: citing, natbib, csquotes

I am trying to make a short quote using `\textquote` from the package `csquotes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
Something before.
\textquote[{\cite{simonovits2003}}]{In most countries private markets}.
\medskip
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{test_quote} 
\end{document}
```

And the bib file `test_quote.bib` is:

```
@book{simonovits2003,
    Author = {Andrus Simonovits},
    Title = {Modeling Pension Systems},
    Year = {2003}}
```

and the result is `"In most countries private markets" (Simonovits (2003))`.

I was expecting `"In most countries private markets" (Simonovits, 2003)`. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you post a short, but complete code showing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're describing is unrelated to the use of `\textquote`, a macro provided by the `csquotes` package. Instead, the issue arises because you use `\cite`, which generates "textual" citation call-outs if the `natbib` citation management package is in use. I.e., the output of `\cite` is of the form `Simonovits (2003)`, not `(Simonovits, 2003)`.

By the way, it's not necessary to encase the `\cite{...}` instruction in an extra pair of curly braces.

Taking into account that `\csquotes` encases the contents of the optional argument of `\textquote` automatically, you should be using `\citealp` instead of `\cite` (or `\citet`) to generate the citation call-out. `\citealp` differs from `\citep` in that it does not encase its output in round parentheses.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{simonovits2003,
  author = "Andr{\'a}s Simonovits",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 2003,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}                 % choose a suitable document class
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}         % for "\citealp" macro
\bibliographystyle{apalike}             % choose a suitable bibliography style
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes} % choose a suitable language option

\begin{document}
\textquote[{\cite{simonovits2003}}]{In most countries private markets}

\textquote[\citealp{simonovits2003}]{In most countries private markets}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```